# Getting "Warning messages: 1: In rms::datadist(data) : HAG_13 is constant"

Tags: r, warnings

I'm trying to make a survival spline plot of a population and I'm getting the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In rms::datadist(data) : HAG_13 is constant
2: In rms::datadist(data) : HAG_13_21 is constant
3: In rms::datadist(data) : HAG_21 is constant
4: In rms::datadist(data) : AF_Flutter is constant
5: In rms::datadist(data) : HF is constant
6: In rms::datadist(data) : MI is constant
```

This is my code:

```
library(plotRCS)

plot_object <- rcsplot(
data = heart_data,
outcome = 'MORTALITY',
time = 'Echo_to_censure_date',
exposure = 'HAG',
covariates = 'Age',
positive = NULL,
group = NULL,
knots = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
knots.line = FALSE,
ref.value = 0,
ref.line = T,
conf.int = T,
conf.level = 0.95,
conf.type = c("shape", "line"),
pvalue = F,
pvalue.digits = 3,
pvalue.position = c(1, 1),
pvalue.label.overall = "P for overall",
pvalue.label.nonlinear = "P for nonlinear",
fontsize = 10,
fontfamily = "serif",
linesize = 0.25,
linecolor = "#0072B5FF",
alpha = 0.1,
xbreaks = c(-5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35),
ybreaks = NULL,
xlab = "Heart Age Gap (years)",
ylab = "Mortality Hazard Ratio (95% CI)",
explain = TRUE,
xlim = c(-5, 30),
ylim = c(0, 8),
main = "Cardiovascular Mortality Hazard with increasing Heart Age Gap"
)
```

These columns named in the warnings do indeed only contain 0 or 1, but as I am not calling them I'd think that wouldn't matter. What could cause this error, and how do I work around it?

Comment: They’re just warnings. What’s the problem?

Comment: No plot was showing up, so I figured it was related to the warnings. But that problem was resolved by downloading and updating some packages.

Comment: "No plot was showing up." So it was an X-Y problem of the sort where you ask about X when the concern was about Y. (You would not expect to have "a plot show up" in most of the plotting paradigms with such code. Assignment to a name is unlikely to cause any image to appear in most of the currently popular R plotting paradigms. There isn't really a close-vote reason that exactly matches this sort of unanswerable request but I'm choosing the "needs further details *raison*. Tags edited since this has nothing to do with either splines or survival analysis.